# Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable laravel-5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am getting this error after I upgrade laravel from 5.2 to 5.4.

```
    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>449</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable. in C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:894
Stack trace:
0 C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container-&gt;notInstantiable('Illuminate\\Cont...')
1 C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container-&gt;build('Illuminate\\Cont...')
2 C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container-&gt;resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...')
3 C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container-&gt;make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
4 C:\xampp\ht in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\valuable-app\dev-master\rest_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php</b> on line <b>894</b>
```

i have already spend a lot of time in solving this but not get a working answer. Please anyone

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Can you share the lines of your container causing the problem?

Comment: it's same like new project

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/target-illuminatecontractsfilesystemfactory-is-not-instantiable

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6226

Comment: And which of these approaches have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to get the answer from these links and try to register directly but not got it

Comment: getting these errors and warnings after the upgrade

Comment: whatever I understand is that this is the issue while creating instance of the above class

Comment: protected function notInstantiable($concrete)
    {
        if (! empty($this->buildStack)) {
            $previous = implode(', ', $this->buildStack);

            $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable while building [$previous].";
        } else {
            $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable.";
        }

        throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
    }

Comment: Followed the [upgrade guides](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)?

Comment: I have already followed this